# How do I generate a certain amount of random numbers on ruby

Tags: ruby

I need to know how to generate 100 numbers between 1 and 1000. So far I have:

```
randnum=1+rand(1000)
```

Answer (score 5):

100 numbers so let's say an array. You can use array's constructor to specify how many items (as a parameter) and how each item has to be defined (as a block)

```
Array.new(100) { rand(1..1_000) }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make an infinite `Enumerator` of random numbers and then take as many as you need:

```
rands = Enumerator.new { |r| loop { r << rand(1..1_000) } }
rands.take(100)
#=> [495, 359, 767, 561, 617, 348, 373, 283, 883, 104...] 
rands.next
#=> 339
```

Answer (score 0):

For N random numbers between 0 and `max`:

```
require 'securerandom'

(0...n).map { SecureRandom.rand(0..max) }
```

For example:

```
n = 100
max = 1000
```

It's generally best to use SecureRandom as the default `rand` is pretty garbage.

Comment: "pretty garbage"? How so?

Comment: @StefanPochmann As in it's not always very random and can repeat if seeded incorrectly or is fairly predictable, which could be a vulnerability. The SecureRandom library isn't harder to use, and it is cryptographically random, so it's a good baseline for any sort of "random number" work. I'm not sure if it's still the case in Ruby, but in many languages `rand` is just a wrapper around the notoriously weak C library `rand` function.

Comment: Not clear whether you mean the seeding is the problem or the generator itself is. And whether you mean repeating due to repeated seed or due to the generator itself. [The documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Kernel.html#method-i-rand) says "See also Random#rand", so I assume it's equivalent to that, and the documentation of the Random class says "PRNGs are currently implemented as a modified Mersenne Twister". And Mersenne Twister is pretty good, has nothing to do with that weak C library function. Also, in ...

Comment: ... many cases you don't care about repetitions caused by repeated seed or you actually *want* that.

Comment: @StefanPochmann It's usually better to use a good, secure method by default and only deviate when you actually want that than to wake up one day with an ugly surprise you can't fix.

Comment: Hmm, maybe. But I still don't think calling it "pretty garbage" is appropriate.

Comment: @StefanPochmann On some platforms it's really, *really* bad, like the RNG only has 16 bits of entropy. You don't want to be surprised by something like that, especially when you can't change it.

Comment: On what platforms?

Comment: @StefanPochmann Ruby runs on a lot of platforms, so you never know what `rand` function that's being bound against. Here's a [talk on `rand()`](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful) which enumerates some of the concerns you should have in mind when picking a random number generator. It's a lot more complicated than people think, which is why using one that's a good default, like `SecureRandom.rand`, is better than the usual `rand` function. Maybe newer versions of Ruby fix some of the ugly `rand` behaviour, but historically it's *bad*.

Comment: I didn't watch the whole video but skimmed the slides and watched a small part. I don't think he's talking about Ruby at all. And he *does* explicitly recommend Mersenne Twister! So rather looks like you just proved yourself wrong.

Comment: @StefanPochmann It'll take some time for me to dig into the exact implementation of the various Ruby rand generators, there's at least three in the standard library, but of those SecureRandom appears to be the strongest. If you're generating things like random API keys you need those to be unpredictable or you'll have serious problems, and while not everything is always that serious, using SecureRandom as a default protects you from occasions when you underestimated how secure you need it to be.

Comment: Well, nothing in the question says anything about security. Quite the contrary, generating 100 numbers between 1 and 1000 rather looks to me like they're doing some simulation/statistics. Who is generating API keys or so in batches of 100? With values from 1 to 1000? There are plenty of reasons to want randomness other than security. When the context *is* security (like in my own password generator), I do use something like SecureRandom as well. But when it isn't, then I prefer the regular one for its advantages. And I don't think it's "pretty garbage".

Comment: @StefanPochmann This is turning into a protracted discussion without any real conclusion. I've expressed my opinion, and you've stated yours, so it's best left at that. Others can make their own decisions that are, at least, better educated because of the points we've raised.